# Spring application with embedded servlet container run error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot

I am learning Spring and I have a problem. I have created standalone application (web service) which run in embedded servlet container. I use Intellij IDEA with gradle. When I run application from IDEA - all work fine. But when I have created jar file and run via console ("java -jar my.jar") I have got error (below). 
I was load official sample (https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service) and it's not work too (via running jar).
I see this link but it not helped me: [Spring Boot: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783391/spring-boot-unable-to-start-embeddedwebapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-embedd)

Please help

Error log:

```
18:47:26.079 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup faile
d org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedde
d container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextE
xception: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedS
ervletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135) ~[ClientsIm.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476) ~[ClientsIm.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120) ~[ClientsIm.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.
java:691) [ClientsIm.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:320) [ClientsIm.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java
:952) [ClientsIm.jar:na]
        at com.clientsim.server.Application.main(Application.java:13) [ClientsIm
.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to st
art EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory
 bean.
```

My build.gradle:

```
group 'ClientsIm'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Comment: What command are you running when you build your jar with Gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something tells me you did not create your jar using gradle ? Perhaps you exported it from intellij ?

#### (1) Build with gradle:

You should build your jar using gradle (to create the jar using `spring-boot-gradle-plugin`). Open a terminal at the root of your project and type:

```
$ gradle build
  ...

$ cd build/libs
$ java -jar yourjar.jar
```

#### (2) Export spring-boot jar from Intellij:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33699764/641627

Comment: Thank you very much! I have used gradle build and jar work fine.